# Wildcarding Compojure Routes gives a warning

Tags: clojure, compojure, clout

The following route works as I would like - i.e. match /pref/ and bind * to the rest of the path.

```
(GET "/pref/*" [*] (do (println *) (resp (str "Hello " *))))
```

However there's a complaint to stdout:

```
WARNING: * should not be used as a route binding.
```

The clout docs suggest that wildcarding with * is fine, the compojure docs don't explain how I should do this idiomatically without provoking the warning, or what the reason for the warning is. I must confess to a certain unease binding * myself although I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some poking around, this seems to satisfy, using the inline regexp functionality to match everything. Still not sure what the warning is for.

```
(GET "/pref/:path{.*}" [path] (do (println path) (resp (str "Hello " path))))
```